# Uploading files using FineUploader in Node.js hangs up server

Tags: node.js, express, fine-uploader

I've been troubleshooting this bug for over two weeks now, and can't find what's going wrong. I've go a page using FineUploader to upload multiple files. I have a collection of items and each needs to get it's own images. so I'm pasing a parameter with the request to identify to which item the images correspond. I also have an uploader for a picture gallery and for a logo.

I trigger the uploads manually and get the request on the server, then set req.on(data, function() { ... }) to upload the files.  This NEVER get's triggered.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onSubmit = function (uploaderName) {
        return function (id, fileName) {
            console.log("Setting parameters...")
            window[uploaderName].setParams({
                farm: $('input[name=farm-name]').val()
            });
        }
    };

    window.logoUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#logo')[0],
        request: {
            endpoint: '/upload/farm/logo'
        },
        autoUpload: false,
        debug: true,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
            sizeLimit: 1024000 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
        },
        text: {
            uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Logo'
        },
        callbacks: {
            onSubmit: onSubmit("logoUploader")
        }
    });

  window.shareLogoUploader = [];
  window.shareLogoUploader[0] = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: $('#share-logo-0')[0],
    request: {
      endpoint: '/upload/farm/share/gallery'
    },
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true,
    validation: {
      allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
      sizeLimit: 1024000 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
    },
    text: {
      uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Logo'
    }
  });

    window.galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#gallery')[0],
        request: {
            endpoint: '/upload/farm/gallery/photo'
        },
        autoUpload: false,
        debug: true,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
            sizeLimit: 2024000 // around 2mbs
        },
        text: {
            uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Pics'
        },
        callbacks: {
            onComplete: function (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                if (responseJSON.success) {
                    console.log(responseJSON, fileName);
                    $('#thumbnails').append('<img src="/uploads/' + fileName + '" width="256px"><input type="hidden" name="photos[]" value="' + fileName + '">');
                }
            },
            onSubmit: onSubmit("galleryUploader")
        }
    });
});

// Shares
var shares = [];
var sharesGallery = [];

$(function () {
    $('section#shares button#add-share').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var title = $('section#shares .control-group input[name=title]');
        var size = $('section#shares .control-group select[name=size]');
        var type = $('section#shares .control-group select[name=type]');
        var price = $('section#shares .control-group input[name=price]');
        var amount = $('section#shares .control-group input[name=amount]');
        var unit = $('section#shares .control-group select[name=unit]');
        var discount_3 = $('input[name=discount-3]').val();
        var discount_6 = $('input[name=discount-6]').val();
        var discount_12 = $('input[name=discount-12]').val();
        var errors = $('section#shares .control-group#errors');
        var delivery_period = $('section#shares .control-group input[name=delivery_period]');
        var delivery_period_es = $('section#shares .control-group input[name=delivery_period_es]');
        var billing_period = $('section#shares .control-group input[name=billing_period]');
        var billing_period_es = $('section#shares .control-group input[name=billing_period_es]');
        var logoUploader = window.shareLogoUploader[shares.length];
        var logoButtonId = "share-logo-" + shares.length;

            shares.push({
                title: title.val(),
                currency: $('select[name=currency]').children(':selected').val(),
                size: size.children(':selected').val(),
                type: type.children(':selected').val(),
                price: price.val() * 100.0,
                unit: unit.children(':selected').val(),
                amount: amount.val(),
                discounts: {
                    '3': [discount_3, price.val() * discount_3 / 100.0],
                    '6': [discount_6, price.val() * discount_6 / 100.0],
                    '12': [discount_12, price.val() * discount_12 / 100.0]
                },
                delivery_period: delivery_period.val(),
                delivery_period_es: delivery_period_es.val(),
                billing_period: billing_period.val(),
                billing_period_es: billing_period_es.val()
            });

            var newLogoButtonId = "share-logo-" + shares.length;

            sharesGallery.push({
                name: type.children(':selected').val() + "-" + size.children(':selected').val(),
                logoUploader: logoUploader
            })
        $("#" + logoButtonId).css('display', 'none');
        $("#" + logoButtonId).parent().append('<div id="' + newLogoButtonId + '"></div>');

        window.shareLogoUploader[shares.length] = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: $("#" + newLogoButtonId)[0],
            request: {
                endpoint: '/upload/farm/share/gallery'
            },
            autoUpload: false,
            debug: true,
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                sizeLimit: 1024000 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
            },
            text: {
                uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Logo'
            }
        });

        console.log(shares);

        return;
    }
});
```

This triggers the uploads correctly, I get the request on the server and handle it this way, then the server hangs on waiting for data that never comes, re req.on Data naver gets triggered. This is the Server side code:

```
var fs = require('fs'), util = require('util'), uuid = require('node-uuid');

var uploadpath = __dirname + "/../public/uploads/";

var slugify = exports.slugify = function(value) {
    return value.toLowerCase().replace(/-+/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g, '');
};
// Route that takes the post upload request and sends the server response
exports.upload = function(req, res) {
    winston.info("Upload parameters", [req.route.params[0], req.query.farm]);
    uploadpath = __dirname + "/../public/uploads/";
    if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
    }
    switch(req.route.params[0]) {
        case 'farm/logo':
            uploadpath += "../farms/" + slugify(req.query.farm);
            if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
            }
            uploadpath += "/" + "logo." + req.header('x-file-name').split(".").pop();
            break;

        case 'farm/gallery/photo':
            uploadpath += "../farms/" + slugify(req.query.farm);
            if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
            }
            uploadpath += "/gallery";
            if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
            }
            var fname = req.header('x-file-name');
            uploadpath += "/" + fname;
            break;

        case 'farm/share/gallery':
            uploadpath += "../farms/" + slugify(req.query.farm);
            if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
            }
            uploadpath += "/shares";
            if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
            }
            uploadpath += "/" + slugify(req.query.share);
            if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
            }
            uploadpath += "/gallery";
            if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
            }
            var fname = req.header('x-file-name');
            uploadpath += "/" + fname;
            break;
        case 'courier/license':
        case 'courier/registration':
            uploadpath += "../couriers/" + slugify(req.query.courier);
            if(!fs.existsSync(uploadpath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(uploadpath);
            }
            var fname = req.header('x-file-name');
            uploadpath += "/" + fname;
            break;

        default:
            var fname = req.header('x-file-name');
            uploadpath += fname;
            break;
    }

    winston.info("Uploading to ", uploadpath);

    uploadFile(req, uploadpath, function(data) {
        if(data.success)
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data), {
                'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
            }, 200);
        else
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data), {
                'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
            }, 404);
    });
}
// Mainfunction to recieve and process the file upload data asynchronously
var uploadFile = function(req, targetfile, callback) {

    // Moves the uploaded file from temp directory to it's destination
    // and calls the callback with the JSON-data that could be returned.
    var moveToDestination = function(sourcefile, targetfile) {
        moveFile(sourcefile, targetfile, function(err) {
            if(!err)
                callback({
                    success : true
                });
            else
                callback({
                    success : false,
                    error : err
                });
        });
    };
    // Direct async xhr stream data upload, yeah baby.
    if(req.xhr) {

        // Be sure you can write to '/tmp/'
        var tmpfile = '/tmp/' + uuid.v1();

        // Open a temporary writestream
        var ws = fs.createWriteStream(tmpfile);
        ws.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("uploadFile() - req.xhr - could not open writestream.");
            callback({
                success : false,
                error : "Sorry, could not open writestream."
            });
        });
        ws.on('close', function(err) {
            moveToDestination(tmpfile, targetfile);
        });
        // Writing filedata into writestream
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            ws.write(data);
        });
        req.on('end', function() {
            ws.end();
        });
    }

    // Old form-based upload
    else {
        moveToDestination(req.files.qqfile.path, targetfile);
    }
};
// Moves a file asynchronously over partition borders
var moveFile = function(source, dest, callback) {
    var is = fs.createReadStream(source)

    is.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('moveFile() - Could not open readstream.', err);
        callback('Sorry, could not open readstream.')
    });
    is.on('end', function() {
        fs.unlinkSync(source);
        callback();
    });
    var os = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    os.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('moveFile() - Could not open writestream.', err);
        callback('Sorry, could not open writestream.');
    });

    is.pipe(os);
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get file uploading with diferent parameters for each bunch of files?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Node example, or perhaps a modified version of the Node example from the server directory of the Fine Uploader Github project.  That example has not been updated to handle multipart encoded requests, which Fine Uploader now sends by default for all browsers.

I don't have much experience with Node, but if you are using Express, it seems like you can/should just use [`req.files`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files) to grab the files associated with the request.

I'll open up a case in the [Widen/fine-uploader-server](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server) repo to remind me to update the node example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the uploadDir config in express.bodyParser but when I check for req.files the object is empty =/ any way to set fine-uploader to it's previous behaviour? it was working before.

Comment: `req.files` should definitely have the file associated with the request.  Most likely there is some other issue with your server-side code, or express is not configured correctly.  I'm not nearly familiar enough with node to advise without doing some reading.  If `req.files` is not working for you, you will need to dig a bit deeper into your code.  While you can tell Fine Uploader to simply stream the file (old default behavior) if the browser supports the File API, you will need to parse MPE requests in IE9 and older no matter what.

Comment: I'm also linking fineuploader like this:
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/3.1.1/fineuploader.min.js

I'll dig into the req.files thing and let you know what I find.

Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Oh.  I assumed you were using a current version of Fine Uploader.  The default behavior change to multipart encoded requests in all browsers didn't happen until 3.2.  You should probably just switch to the latest version of Fine Uploader: 3.4.  That will be much easier to troubleshoot.  3.1.1 is quite old.

Comment: I've decided to move to jquery-uploader and uploade directly to Amazon S3 to solve other issues that I hand and handle CDN content delivery. Thanks for your postings Ray, they really helped me to get through troubleshooting. Making this as Answered.

Comment: You're welcome @Nevtep.  Note that uploading directly to S3 is a high-priority feature planned for Fine Uploader.  I hope to begin work on that in the next month or two.  So, feel free to check back if you're interested.

Comment: Ok thanks, I realized I need to gzip/minify/preprocess images so direct-upload will not be my final path. I'll give fine uploader 3.4 a change to see if I can get the req.files populated.

Comment: Ray - I'm running into the very same problem with fine-uploader and Express. I'm also using an adaptation of your example code, and con't quite suss out how to get around Express being helpful and handling the file without letting me properly respond to the callbacks. If anyone has any working examples of Node + Express + fineuploader, I would love to be able to look at them!

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I guess this was five years ago, but my server is getting a blank body on my request object from fine-uploader, almost certainly because I'm doing something wrong. But I don't know what it is. I only need a signed policy; I'm uploading directly from the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, if anyone (like me) needs a decent and simple example of implementing Fine Uploader with their node.js/express app - I finally was able to get it working.  Turns out, I was making everything far more difficult for myself than necessary, and the Fine Uploader server example doesn't make it clear how easy this is now with newer versions of express (this is with express@3.1.1).

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir: __dirname + '/uploads'}));

app.get('/upload', localQuery, function(request, response) {
    //This serves up our 
    response.render('index');

});

app.post('/uploadhander', function (request, response, next) {

    var fileName = request.files.qqfile.name
    var savePath = __dirname + '/process/';

    //after upload, rename the file, then respond to fineuploader to tell it of success
    fs.rename(request.files.qqfile.path, savePath + fileName, function(err) {
    if (err != null) {
        response.send(JSON.stringify({success: false, error: err}), {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, 404);
    } else {
        response.send(JSON.stringify({success: true}), {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, 200);
    }
    });

});
```

and here is the bit of the jade template for /upload that handles the Fine Uploader options (your options would obviously vary):

```
  div.span12
    h4 Upload a show file
    #jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader
      script(type='text/javascript')
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
            debug: false,
            request: {
              endpoint: '/uploadhander',
              params: {
                hostname: "#{locals.query.hostname}",
                hostport: "#{locals.query.hostport}",
                bucket: "#{locals.query.bucket}",
                nid: "#{locals.query.nid}",
                title: "#{locals.query.title}",
              },
              chunking: {
                enabled: true,
              },
              resume: {
                enabled: true,
              },
            }
          });
        });
```

I should point out that I haven't yet tested the resume functionality, but I **can** verify that multiple uploads are being processed, with much less code than published examples show.  Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Note to any observers: @Logickal opened up a pull request on Widen/fine-uploader-server with his improved node server-side example.  It is now part of the server-side examples repo.  Thanks @Logickal!

Comment: Need one of these for the case where the client handles the upload and only needs a signed policy from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's more useful and simple to use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) with express.js 
.My server side code look like this

```
var multer  = require('multer');

var upload = multer({
    dest : path.join(__dirname , '../public/uploads/')
});

router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {

    upload(req, res, function (err) {

        if (err) 
            response.send(JSON.stringify({success: false, error: err}), {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, 404);
        else
            res.send(JSON.stringify({success: true}), {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, 200);

    });


});

module.exports = router;
```